# pass data to child component when clicked on card in parent component ( card has image name id and more info ) angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to pass data when clicked on the card(card has images, id, name, and more) from the parent(nfts) to the child(main) component and render the information in the child component.

I tried to use @Input() but I don't get the value on the child component, and also tried using the EventEmitter but I could not pass the value via the **variable.emit(value)**
or is there a better way achieve this

**nft.html**

```
<app-main [nftId]="ItemClicked"></app-main>
<div class="container">
    <div class="collectionCard" *ngFor="let data of nftData" 
    (click)="getId(data.token_id,data.image_url,data.name)">
        <img src="{{data.image_url}}" alt="nf img" >
        <div class="details">
            <div class="name">
                {{data.name}} 
                <div class="id">#. {{data.token_id}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="priceContainer">
            <img src="assets/assets/weth.png" alt="symbol" class="weithImage">
            <div class="price">{{data.traits[0]?.value}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**nft.ts**

```
export class NftsComponent implements OnInit {
  nftData:any =[];
  ItemClicked:any = []; 
 
  getdata(){
    fetch('https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?asset_contract_address=0x617d411DE5a4D5b668EBAa22Edc7bCdbb88285c4&order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=5')
   .then(response =>response.json())
   .then(response =>{
     const data = response.assets;
     this.nftData = data;
     console.log(this.nftData);
   })
   .catch(err =>console.error(err))
  }

  getId(id:any,img:string,name:string){
    this.ItemClicked = id; 
    this.ItemClicked = img;
    this.ItemClicked = name;
  }
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getdata();
    
  }
```

**main.ts**

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() nftId:any;

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit(){
    console.log( this.nftId);
  }
}
```

I want to receive data in the main.ts

stackbliz link -
https://github.com/HemanthGirimath/nft-cryptoPunk-clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add implement ngOnchanges method inside the child component

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges{
  @Input() nftId:any;

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit(){
    console.log( this.nftId);
  }

ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges) {
    if(change["nftId"]) {
      console.log(change["nftId"]);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It does what I wanted to do thank you for the response, but it's not **dynamically updating my clicks every time**. What I'm trying to achieve is every time I click on the nft card it should update the values like id image and name

Comment: so you need to pass object parent child using input not just id.

Comment: I am doing that @ nft.html I'm using `(click)="getId(data.token_id,data.image_url,data.name)"  and in nft.ts   
  `getId(id:any,img:string,name:string){
    this.ItemClicked = id; 
    this.ItemClicked = img;
    this.ItemClicked = name;
  }`

Comment: You are using only 1 variable ItemClicked  not full object

Comment: can you point me in the rite direction if its not too much to ask?

Comment: First declare Object

ItemClicked  : any;

getId(id:any,img:string,name:string){
    this.ItemClicked.id = id; 
    this.ItemClicked.img = img;
    this.ItemClicked.name = name;
  }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First declare Object

```
ItemClicked  : any;

getId(id:any,img:string,name:string){
    this.ItemClicked.id = id; 
    this.ItemClicked.img = img;
    this.ItemClicked.name = name;
  }
```

Comment: ok, so I did pass it as an object, and I'm receiving the data as an object. But I still don't understand how to display it and dynamically update it every time I click on the nft card. sorry for the trouble. I'm stuck at this for a long and I can't find any resource if you have an example please let me take a look                                                                                                                           Take a look [link](https://github.com/HemanthGirimath/nft-cryptoPunk-clone)

Comment: can you make the stackblitz.

Comment: [stackbliz] - (https://stackblitz.com/github/HemanthGirimath/nft-cryptoPunk-clone)

Comment: I cant see your response anymore (hope you didn't delete the comment), But I did take a look and it was working but it had an error (cannot read property of undefined ) in the console,  it is working in stackbliz but not on the browser

Comment: Anyways thank you for taking your time to answer my question. I did figure out the error with your help it was because I was accessing values even before the API call was made 
and solved it with nftId?.image_url. Thank you Rutvik Maniya